# Make Windows 7 C++/CLI GUI look the same under Windows 10

Tags: c++, user-interface, visual-c++, c++-cli, multiplatform

I have a Visual Studio 2017 app, written (historically) in C++/CLI under Windows 7. Now I'm trying to run in Windows 10. The look of all buttons and other UI elements changes to match Win 10 style, ex:
[Win 7 vs Win 10 look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IJss.jpg)
Is there a way to keep the Windows 7 look?

Running in compatibility mode doesn't affect UI.
Xaml or manifest options don't seem to apply here (or I cannot find a way to introduce them to my project). PresentationFramework reference doesn't provide anything useful either.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: That's generally considered desirable. Any reason why you can't just live with it?

Comment: I personally like it, but there are UI specs and branding issues which require certain look and feel to deal with.